# Identifying Bottleneck on Laravel app with Blackfire Profiling

Tags: php, laravel-5, blackfire, asgardcms

I'm trying to get my TTFB down to under 200ms. Currently it is over 600ms.

My app uses Laravel with AsgardCMS. I have implemented very little custom code, and the database has 28 tables with less than 100 records in total.

I have installed Redis caching (and turned caching on), and run `php artisan optimize`.

I am also using Nginx with Apache via `Engintron`.

Basically I have tried to eliminate as much of the bottleneck as I can!

However, after installing Blackfire, it is reporting that `Composer\Autoload\includeFile` is taking a total of 250ms on its own (over 299 calls).

`Illuminate\Container\Container::build` is also being called 141 times with total time of 49ms.

I accept that it's normal for the autoloader to be called this many times, but should it really be taking 250ms?

My VPS has 2 cores (Intel Xeon CPU) and 4GB RAM (dedicated). I just upgraded from 1 core and 2GB RAM, but barely noticed any difference. Disks are SSD. Running on WHM/cPanel btw. Around 10 sites on the server, but none of them particularly high traffic, and these tests have been run during the quietest periods.

In the last test run, Blackfire reported:-

```
Time: 696ms
I/O Wait: 149ms
CPU time: 548ms
SQL Queries: 2.38ms
```

Any ideas? Pretty please...

Comment: *I am also using Nginx with Apache* a lot of people in other technologies may use nginx as a **reverse proxy** but I just don't get it when it comes to PHP, isn't it enough ? why you need apache too ?

Comment: Do you have **opcache** enabled ? OPcache improves PHP performance by storing precompiled script bytecode in shared memory, thereby removing the need for PHP to load and parse scripts on each request. It helped me a lot with my Drupal website, when I check the statisctics it's just amazing!

Comment: @teeyo - yes using nginx as a reverse proxy, only because I wanted to see if it produced any performance gains, and as the server uses WHM/cPanel I didn't want to completely get rid of Apache...yet (not sure if even possible).

Comment: You can also try to use `varnish` instead of Redis, I had once a page with a TTFB of 1.5s and with **varnish** it loaded in less then 100ms

Comment: Prior to Laravel 5.4 Running `php artisan optimize` should generate a compiled classes file which would be included only once and will include all Laravel framework files. Therefore there should not be calls to `includeFile` for framework files. You can add additional files and packages to be compiled in `/config/compile.php`

Comment: You may also take a look to see if your server is well configured sending the right caching headers, and that compression is enabled, extensions like : `deflate` & `expires` may improve server performance (at least it did for me)

Comment: @teeyo, yes `opcache` is enabled according to `phpinfo`.  I'll have a look at Varnish - i'm guessing you're referring to entire page caching with Varnish?  Also, re your last comment, I have compression enabled, and proper cache headers, but this is to do with PHP, not browser caching etc. Thanks.

Comment: @apokryfos - i'm using 5.4 - so does that mean `php artisan optimize` isn't doing what it used to?

Comment: Yes varnish is about caching all the page, it acts like a reverse proxy, if the page is already cached the request won't even reach your web server, varnish will take care of it, but I don't know if that's suitable for your case

Comment: @teeyo - page caching is suitable in this case, as the site in question is pretty much static, but I'm having the same issue with other sites on the server which are more dynamic and need server interaction. I would prefer to get to the bottom of the class loading issue first, else i'd just be masking it don't you think?

Comment: I agree, well apart from opcache I can't think of anything to improve the performance of your PHP (except if you want to move to PHP7 :p)

Comment: @pavsid yes it seems to no longer be the case. Now it just basically runs `composer dump-autoload --optimize` which switches to the static class loader which has a mapping of each class to a path (making less directory lookups)

Comment: Maybe you could take a look at this discussion, it says all I  wanted to say : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/adventures-in-increasing-laravel-performance

Comment: The reason it was removed as discussed in [GitHub](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/17003) seems to be that if you're using PHP 7+ then it's better to use OpCache than pre-compile all classes

Comment: WOW. Following these comments, and the comments on the link by @teeyo I decided to test out PHP7 for this website in question. WHM made it easy to enable PHP7 for this account only, so that was pretty straightforward. Ran another test, which came out about 400ms - awesome, but still not under 200ms. So, I decided to try and enable `PHP-FPM`, which also was a sinch via WHM... F*** ME! Now i'm getting around 100ms! And to top it off, if I disable `Engintron`, I shave another 10-20ms off that!! Thanks all for your input... hope this helps others...

Comment: Wow really amazing stuff, will you can write a good answer, so maybe this will help someone in the future :) happy for you!

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I didn't get to the bottom of whether or not there was an issue with the server, or the PHP code, or if the "slowness" of the app was to be expected, following the comments on this thread and the comments on the link provided by @teeyo (https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/adventures-in-increasing-laravel-performance) I decided to test out `PHP7`.

WHM made it easy to enable PHP7 for this account only, so that was pretty straightforward. Ran another test, which came out about 400ms - awesome, but still not under 200ms.

So, I decided to try and enable `PHP-FPM`, which also was a sinch via WHM...

F*** ME! Now i'm getting around 100ms! And to top it off, if I disable `Engintron`, I shave another 10-20ms off that!! (Although that  probably isn't recommended for high traffic sites, as then it won't benefit from `nginx` reverse proxy).

Anyway, thanks all for your input... hope this helps others...